# jQuery animation | prevent function trigger redundancy

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

How to keep track of the following animation to see if it is already applied or not?
Usually I would just set a variable to 1 or true while its on, but this animation is applied to multiple elements based on class..

```
function animateDiv(what) {  
    $(what).animate({ backgroundPosition:"0px -250px"
    },8000).css('background-position','0px -250px');

    $(what).animate({
        backgroundPosition:"0px 0px"
    },8000).css('background-position','0px 0px'); 
} 


$(document).on( 'hover', '.animation-div', function(){ animateDiv(this); } );
```

Comment: Make the flag according to the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is this:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.animation-div', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasData('done')) {
        $(this).data('done');
        animateDiv(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this answer questions, but some of this could be helpful...

```
function addAnotherClass($self) {
  $self.toggleClass('another_class_for_reference');
}

$('.animation-div').hover(
  function() {
    var $self = $(this);

    $self.animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    $self.addClass('active');
    addAnotherClass($self);
  },
  function() {
    var $self = $(this);

    $self.animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
    $self.removeClass('active');
    addAnotherClass($self);
  }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/RBhAZ/